# My function just keeps looping, is it something to do with firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My function is just looping at the print statement and not going into the ref db.collection Am I doing something wrong here? Thank you for any help. Im not really sure where to go, is this the best way to loop throw most of the data

```
func rat(){
        var x = 0
        while x != self.uniqueNumber{
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let indexString = String(x)
        print(x)
        let ref = db.collection("leaderboard").document(indexString)

        ref.getDocument { (document,error) in

                           if error != nil{
                               print("cant get data")

                           }
                           if document != nil && document!.exists{

                           if let documentdata = document?.data() {
                            self.check = documentdata["points"] as! Int
                            self.uid = documentdata["uid"] as! String
                            x = x+1
                            print(x)
                            print("The user's ID was\(self.uid)")
                            if (self.check > self.firstPlace.placePoints){
                                self.secondPlace.placePoints = self.firstPlace.placePoints
                                self.secondPlace.placeNames = self.firstPlace.placeNames
                                self.firstPlace.placePoints = self.check
                                self.firstPlace.placeNames = self.uid

                                print("First Place was set to:\(self.firstPlace.placeNames)")
                            }else if(self.check < self.firstPlace.placePoints && self.secondPlace.placePoints < self.check){
                                self.thirdPlace.placePoints = self.secondPlace.placePoints
                                self.thirdPlace.placeNames = self.secondPlace.placeNames
                                self.secondPlace.placePoints = self.check
                                self.secondPlace.placeNames = self.uid
                                print("Second Place was set to:\(self.firstPlace.placeNames)")
                            }else if(self.check < self.secondPlace.placePoints && self.thirdPlace.placePoints < self.check){
                                self.thirdPlace.placePoints = self.check
                                self.thirdPlace.placeNames = self.uid
                                print("Third Place was set to:\(self.firstPlace.placeNames)")
                            }
                            }
                            if(x == self.uniqueNumber!-1){

                                 print("This is the escape out")
                                self.setGuys()

                            }
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Asynchronous methods don't work that way. You should wait for `getDocument` to complete before you call it again.

Comment: I would say this is the wrong approach - placing async calls in a tight loop is generally a bad idea. Also, what you're expecting is not really clear. Can you make a small code example of what you're trying to do? Questions should include a description of what the code is supposed to do as well as what the objective is. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try move the `while x != self.uniqueNumber` to inside the `getDocument`

```
func rat(){
  var x = 0
  let db = Firestore.firestore()
  let indexString = String(x)

  let ref = db.collection("leaderboard").document(indexString)

  ref.getDocument { (document,error) in

    if error != nil{
      print("cant get data")
    }
    while x != self.uniqueNumber {
      if document != nil && document!.exists{
        if let documentdata = document?.data() {
          x = x+1
        }
        if(x == self.uniqueNumber!-1){
          self.setGuys()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```